# What do these warning messages mean when reading shapefiles in R?

Tags: r, rgdal

When I read in a shapefile with `readOGR`, the following warnings are raised.

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI =
> morphFromESRI,  ... :   Discarded ellps WGS 84 in CRS definition:
> +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
>
> 2: In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI = morphFromESRI,  ... :   Discarded datum
> WGS_1984 in CRS definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0
> +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
>
> 3: In showSRID(wkt2, "PROJ") :   Discarded ellps WGS 84 in CRS
> definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0
> +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
>
> 4: In showSRID(wkt2, "PROJ") : Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition
>
> 5: In sp::proj4string(obj) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in
> output

What do they mean, and how to tackle them?

Comment: How about this vignette? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html